# Duplicate Class/Entity Mapping Error

Tags: nhibernate

I have this domain hierarchy:

User -> EntityWithAuditDate -> Entity

Here is the domain: (simplified)

```
public class User : EntityWithAuditDate 
{ 

      public User(){} 

      public virtual string Name { get; set; } 

} 


public abstract class EntityWithAuditDate : Entity 
{ 

       public EntityWithAuditDate() { } 


       public virtual DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; } 
}
```

And the mapping(simplified):

```
    <class name="User" table="Users" abstract="false"> 
            <id name="Id" type="Int32" column="UserId"> 
                    <generator class="identity" /> 
            </id> 
            <property name="Name" type="String"/> 
            <property name ="CreatedAt"/> 
    </class>
```

When I ran a [mapping integration unit test](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/08/09/NHibernateMappingCreatingSanityChecks.aspx), I got 
this error:

> Tests.AltNetTime.Data.NHibernateMaps.MappingIntegrationTests.CanConfirmData­baseMatchesMappings:
>   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException
>   : An invalid or  incomplete
>   configuration was used while creating
>   a SessionFactory.  Check
>   PotentialReasons collection, and
>   InnerException for more detail.
>
> - Database was not configured
>     through Database method.
>
>   ---->
>     FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException
>     : An invalid  or incomplete
>     configuration was used while creating
>     a SessionFactory.  Check
>     PotentialReasons collection, and
>     InnerException for more detail.
> - Database was not configured
>     through Database method.
>
>   ----> NHibernate.MappingException :
>     Could not compile the mapping 
>     document: (XmlDocument)    ---->
>     NHibernate.DuplicateMappingException :
>     Duplicate class/entity  mapping
>     AltNetTime.Core.User  TearDown :
>     System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
>     : Exception has  been thrown by the
>     target of an invocation.    ---->
>     System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException
>     : The given  key was not present in
>     the dictionary.

The unit test passed if the User class inherits from Entity instead. 
Also, I had to remove the CreatedAt property from the mapping file. 
Apparently, there was something wrong with the EntityWithAuditDate 
class. I am not sure what caused the duplicate class/entity mapping. 
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you encounter this problem even with this "simplified" code? Perhaps you optimized the problem away...

Comment: What else could I be missing? I left out some properties to make the question shorter. But the critical parts are there. Thanks.

Comment: I mean, you get FluentNHibernate exceptions, but there isn't anything about FNH in the code. I just asked if you could actually reproduce the issue with the simplified code, or if it is just a guess. If you can't explain an issue, you should never guess what's critical.

Comment: Stefan, please look at my second response to anwser #1. I think I have figured out the cause of the problem. Thanks for answering my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change IsBaseType convension in your project. Additional information you can find [here](http://blog.jagregory.com/2009/01/26/fluent-nhibernate-auto-mapping-and-base-classes/)

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. I have seen it before. How do I do that on hbm? I am not using Fluent NHibernate here.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. I have been using Sharp Architecture. By default, it uses Fluent NHibernate. But I ran into an error in its auto-mapping recently. So, I switched to hbm to work around the problem. Since then, I get so used to hbm files that I forgot about the conventions in Fluent NHibernate. You are right. I am missing the IsBaseType convension.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate class/entity mapping is often triggered if you copy&paste your *.hbm files and forget to change the

So in two *.hbm files you have the same value in the name attribute.